# Simple bound for $L^p$ norm

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces

Is there a bound for any $1<p<\infty$ or specifically $p=6$ such that

$$||u||_{L^{p}(U)}\leq C ||u||_{H^{1}(U)}  $$

Where $U$ is an open bounded set of class $C^2$ in $\mathbb{R^3}$

and $H^{1}$ is the usual Sobolev norm.

Comment: thanks im new to Sobolev spaces, maybe add as an answer with a link or something and i can accept it as answer ? :)

Answer (score 0):

It's is just the [Sobolev embedding theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_inequality#Sobolev_embedding_theorem) when $p=6$.